# BeautifulSoup test object type

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Good afternoon,

I'm using BeautifulSoup to load and parse the content of an html file.

My input looks like this

```
<tbody id="data">

    <tr>
<td>
  some text </td>
</tr>
```

My code snippet looks like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('table.htm') as f:
    src_html=BeautifulSoup(f,"html.parser")
table=src_html.find(id="data")
type(table.contents[0])  # bs4.element.NavigableString
type(table.contents[1])  # bs4.element.Tag
```

Because my table has several cells I want to get the cells whose type is bs4.element.Tag, how can I do something like

```
for c in table.children:
    if type(c) is bs4.element.Tag then do something
```

Thanks for your help

Simon

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to extract from the table?

Comment: I just want to extract the cell (<td>) content but it looks like every cell is separated with a '\r' that is represented as a NavigableString that I want to get rid off

Comment: I think I found what went wrong with my code

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to to answer to my question

```
from bs4.element import NavigableString, Tag
cells = [ t for t in table.contents if isinstance(t, Tag) ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this really was not obvious to me. I still don't understand why couldn't just do `isinstance(mybs4elementTag, type('bs4.element.Tag'))`